# natural isomorphism for modules

Tags: modules, tensor-products

This is Proposition D.26 in Jeffrey Lee's book *Manifolds and Differential Geometry*. If $V$ is an $R$-module, then we have natural isomorphisms $$V\otimes{}R\rightarrow{}V\rightarrow{}R\otimes{}V$$given on decomposable elements as $v\otimes{}r\rightarrow{}rv\rightarrow{}r\otimes{}v$ (assuming that $R$ is commutative).

I am probably just being stupid here, but how is this not a counterexample? Let $V=\mathbb{R}^{2}$ and $R=\mathbb{R}$. Then $$\left(\begin{array}{c}3\\1\end{array}\right)\otimes{}2\rightarrow{}\left(\begin{array}{c}6\\2\end{array}\right)$$and$$\left(\begin{array}{c}6\\2\end{array}\right)\otimes{}1\rightarrow{}\left(\begin{array}{c}6\\2\end{array}\right)$$

Comment: Not sure what makes you think this is a counterexample.

Comment: those two elements are equal

Answer (score 1):

Thank you, Kenta. For modules, $r(v\otimes{}w)=rv\otimes{}w=v\otimes{}rw$, therefore the "counterexample" is no counterexample. All good now.